# How to save and restore Android Studio user interface settings?

Tags: android-studio, installation

Android Studio allows the user to customize certain features, such as editor settings and coding styles. On Windows boxes, the default folder for these settings appears to be C:\Users\{username}\.AndroidStudio{version}\config. I'm looking for documentation for these files so that we can decide which files should be under version control.

The goals are: 1) to have consistent UI settings for a group of developers; and 2) to have an easy way to configure a new Android Studio install.

So far, the following files look interesting:

```
...\config\templates\user.xml               User-defined code templates
...\config\options\editor.codeinsight.xml   Editor settings & code insight
...\config\options\editor.xml               Editor settings
...\config\options\cachedDictionary.xml     User additions to spelling dictionary.
...\config\codestyles\Default_1_.xml        Code formatting
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It seems that the user interface has changed since the last answer.

Now as of Android Studio 4.2 Bata 1 on Windows
You have to go to `File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Export Setting` to see the same window.

If you can't find the `File > Import Settings` menu, try accessing `File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Export Setting`.

[image: ScreenShat]

There may be differences on the version or operating system.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 103):

You can go `File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Export Settings` then you get to choose exactly the settings to export and you get a single `settings.jar` file.

The reverse process is `File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Export Setting > choose settings.jar`

[image]

Comment: This looks promising. As you say, we'd only need to maintain a single file, and it's likely that a later File -> Import Settings would do the right thing even if the "importing" Android Studio had a higher version number than the settings.jar file.

Comment: Actually i lost that **_settings.jar_** file is there any way for restoring that file?
i have login with gmail id in android studio dose gmail account help me for resorting? waiting for your response.

Comment: @Arbaz.in you should use [settings repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#settings-repository) for syncing or keeping a backup of your IDE settings, plugins, etc. It's easy to setup. If you don't have a paid GiHub account (which gives you access to private repo), I'd suggest that you use Bitbucket, but you have to have a private repo (don't ever put in on public repo!).

Comment: Hi folks, The above solution have never worked for me, maybe I got the wrong idea about the UI Settings but I was expecting to keep all the configs of my windows (size, location, view mode, etc, etc , etc) after restart AS or import the file in a new AS installation, but does not works. I still programming in Eclipse with java/kotlin and works fine but since AS 0.+++ I never saw this working: If I restart my AS it loses all the configs, I must re-configure everything again, what's the ideia this property UI Settings? Any solution? Cheers

Comment: 2022 users: This option is now located in `File` -> `Manage IDE settings` -> `Export settings`

Answer (score 1):

On Android Studio 3 on Mac, it was `configure > Export settings`, resulting in a `settings.zip` file.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is so badly implemented, in case you selected some custom folder and now the export button is disabled: you also need to manually specify a `_name_.zip`, the Android Studio is incapable of doing it itself, ex: `x:\settings.zip`

It might be obvious, but it did gave me a small headache this morning.

Comment: This was quite helpful, Thank you !!