# How can I save All Android Studio Configuration & Settings?

Tags: android-studio, build, configuration, compiler-errors, settings

It happened to me too many times that I did some changes in the Android Studio environment (for example update Gradle version, update Build-Tools, installing new components or plugins that I needed in order to solve some errors that I got) and after that, previous versions that I saved & that where 100% compiled/Built successfully, are suddenly giving me errors.

I want to be able to take a backup of my project that was built OK just a few days or weeks ago, and make it compile again without errors. For that I need to restore the Android Studio environment to the same configuration that it was when I compiled that backup on the first time.

So, how can I save & restore Android Studio's configuration/Settings?

Hope that the question is clear.

Thanks very much.

Comment: follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862767/3635530

Comment: Thanks, I saw this post yesterday before asking my question but I doubt that this is what I need. As I understand this saves only simple editor's settings like fonts color, style and things like that, It doesn't save & restore the Android Studio SDK version, Build-Tools, Gradle and so on. I don't think that It will help.